# iOS: Speaker plays sounds even when mute switch is turned on

Tags: ios

I'm building an app where the user can shoot a video.
We've noticed that after presenting the camera and dismissing it, the mute switch is no longer respected and the sound from the video is audible! The video is played with an AVPlayer.

Is this a bug for Apple?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. AVPlayer lets you categorize your audio playback to tell iOS your *intent*. Here's how to set it:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:cat error:&err];
```

where `cat` is one of

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient: String
AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient: String
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback: String
AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord: String
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord: String
AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing: String
AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute: String
```

For example, the documentation for `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` says

> When using this category, your app audio continues with the Silent switch set to silent or when the screen locks.

Setting it to `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` should make it respect the Mute button.

Comment: Ooooh, this is why sometimes videos unexpectedly have audio - and wake up my wife at night. Sure wish Apple would consider the user's "intent" for a mute switch, and not the developers.

Comment: For that you have the volume control :)

Comment: And there's a reason that I learned the difference. Got bug reports on exactly that :)

Comment: So which one do I use to ensure that the app respects the mute switch? Sound should be there when switch is on, but sound should be silent when switch is off?

Comment: Did you try `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`? Otherwise check the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Modes

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work - problem only happens after dismissing the camera.

Comment: Maybe the camera resets the audio session category and you have to reset it afterwards?

Comment: I put that code snippet in ViewDidAppear to ensure its run after camera dismissal